# Delete a file instead of marking it for deletion

Tags: c++, c, file, winapi

I am writing a service for Windows (from XP to 8.1). I need to recursively delete a folder and I use `DeleteFile` and `RemoveDirectory` for that.
I don't want to use `SHFileOperation` because it has the `MAX_PATH` limit.

The problem is that sometimes, `RemoveDirectory` fails with `ERROR_DIR_NOT_EMPTY`, even if the directory is empty.
I found out that this is because `DeleteFile` works asynchronously, it only "marks" a file for deletion. Therefore, adding a small delay (Sleep) before calling `RemoveDirectory` fixes the issue. But I am looking for a cleaner method.

So, is there a way to ensure that the marked files are well and truly deleted?

I already tried to call `FlushFileBuffers` directly on the directory, without success.

Edit: Some are claiming that `NtDeleteFile` can delete a file even if there are handles open on it. I just checked that and it's wrong, at least on Windows 8.1: the file is removed only when all the handles are closed.

Comment: [`...the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Looks like someone is opening a file with FILE_SHARE_DELETE and the Sleep you added just happens to move the RemoveDirectory call after the last CloseHandle. Can you identify the opener and determine whether it's under your control? If it is, you'll have to make it cooperate with the deletion process. No idea, how would you prevent an unrelated process to deny you the deletion of the directory by holding a file opened :S

Comment: The only realistic solution is to retry after a short delay.  You'll probably find that a few milliseconds is enough.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use SHFileOperation because it has the MAX_PATH limit.

On Vista+, you can (and should) use [`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx) instead of `SHFileOperation()`.  Then you are not limited to any path length limitations, and it can be used safely in a service, unlike `SHFileOperation()`:

[Is it wrong to call SHFileOperation from a service?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/12/06/10474322.aspx)

[Is it wrong to call SHFileOperation from a service? Revised](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/11/21/10574758.aspx)

[So you decided to call SHFileOperation from a service, at least remember to disable copy hooks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/05/22/10616414.aspx)

> So, is there a way to ensure that the marked files are well and truly deleted?

Not really. The files are either in use, or not cleared from the cache manager, or the like. `If DeleteFile()` succeeds, you know the file will be deleted *eventually*. You just have to give the system time to *actually* delete it.  If you receive `ERROR_DIR_NOT_EMPTY`, wait a few seconds and try again.  If you keep getting `ERROR_DIR_NOT_EMPTY` after several attempts, either fail your operation since the folder is clearly not ready to be deleted yet, or else just keep trying until it finally succeeds, enumerating files periodically (in case new files are created).

Comment: IFileOperation would remove the compatibility with XP...
Of course, I can just wait in the case I get ERROR_DIR_NOT_EMPTY, but what I am trying to do is to synchronize data at system shutdown, so everything must be as fast as possible. And this is also why I cannot start reliably a process such as cmd.exe with the rd command.
That said, I just made some further tests and it seems that the culprit was Explorer: by closing all the windows of Explorer, the issue does no longer occur. But this does not really help me, since there may be other processes that do similar things.

Comment: If this is during system shutdown, you can't really wait too long. Even if you are using `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` (also Vista+ only) to block shutdown while you wait, the user can override you and tell Windows to force terminate your app. On XP only, you can block shutdown almost indefinitely.  But yes, either way, Explorer has a habit of keeping folders/files open in-use while it is displaying them.

Comment: @v77 why not delay removal until reboot with `MoveFileEx` and `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`? Also, you should put that bit about shutdown in the question, it sounds like relevant information to me

Comment: @Remy: On Vista+, there is the SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN notification which can give as much time as we want. But if there is a large number of folders that cannot be deleted immediately, this will will take a lot of time and for a shutdown, it's not acceptable.

Comment: @v77: All the more reason to delay the deletion until the next system startup, like Diego suggested.

Comment: @Diego: yes, this could have been a solution, but not in my case, because where I want to write can be an image file that must be first mounted.