# Could DropBox interfere with DeleteFile()/rename()

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, windows-10, dropbox

I had the following code which got executed every two 
minutes all day long:

```
int sucessfully_deleted = DeleteFile(dest_filename);

if (!sucessfully_deleted)
{
    // this never happens
}

rename(source_filename,dest_filename);
```

Once every several hours the rename() would fail with errno=13 (EACCES). The files involved were all sitting on a DropBox directory and I had a hunch that DropBox could be the cause. I figured that it might just be possible that the DeleteFile() function may return with a non-zero successfully_deleted but actually DropBox could still be busy doing some stuff in relation to the deletion that prevented rename() from succeeding. What I did next was to change rename() to my_rename() which would attempt a rename() and upon any failure would Sleep() for one second and try a second time. Sure enough that has worked perfectly ever since. What's more, I get a diagnostic message displaying first-attempt-failures every several hours. It has never failed on the second attempt.

So you could say that the problem is entirely solved... but I would like to understand what might be going on so as to better defend myself against any related DropBox issues in the future...

Really I would like to have a new super_delete() function which does not return until the file is *properly* deleted and finished with in all respects.

Comment: Are you aware that 13 is `EACCES` aka "*Permission denied*"?

Comment: On what operating system was it?

Comment: @MichaelVeksler: From "*`DeleteFile()`*" I concluded it's Windows.

Comment: Question edited to answer comments.

Comment: To me this looks as if the `DeleteFile()` function does not delete "atomically", but somehow the request for deletion gets queued. So your approach to retry made sense. On the other hand, as we do not know how long "queueing" *could* take ....

Comment: Why not use the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-delete) instead of going via any complicated (seemingly unreliable)  drive/path mappings.

Comment: Did you try `unlink()` instead of `DeleteFile()`? MSC has [`_unlink()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/unlink-wunlink?view=vs-2017).

Comment: I didn't try unlink()... what makes you think it would behave differently?

Comment: @alk - unlink not for windows. file can not be deleted until the last handle to the file is closed. but begin from WIN10_RS1 exist `FileDispositionInformationEx` and `FileRenameInformationEx` which support flag `FILE_RENAME_POSIX_SEMANTICS` - *replacing a file even if there are existing handles to it.* and `FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS` (*When marking a file for deletion using FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS, the link gets removed from the visible namespace as soon as the POSIX delete handle has been closed*)- this is and "unlink" functional

Comment: so if you want this for win10 rs1+ (you have tag *windows-10*) you can use `FileDispositionInformationEx` with flag `FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS`. but better instead delete than rename - this this in single operation `FileRenameInformationEx`

Comment: "*what makes you think it would behave differently?*" Its documentation. You would most likely get the `EACCES` by `_unlink()` already. And if you did not get it you probably also would not get it from `rename()` any more.

Comment: @alk - `_[w]unlink` under windows simply call `DeleteFile` - it nothing can do in this case

Comment: @RbMm: Oops, indeed. I misread `_unlink()`'s documentation. Please excuse.

Answer (score 3):

under windows request to delete file really never delete file just. it mark it *FCB* (*File Control Block*) with special flag (`FCB_STATE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`). real deletion will be only when the last file handle will be closed.

> The [`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore,
>   the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is
>   closed. Subsequent calls to `CreateFile` to open the file fail with
>   `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

also if exist section ( memory-mapped file ) open on file - file even can not be marked for delete. api call fail with `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE`. so in general impossible always delete file.

in case exist another open handles for file (but not section !) begin from windows 10 rs1 exist new functional for delete - [`FileDispositionInformationEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class) with [`FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information_ex). in this case:

> Normally a file marked for deletion is not actually deleted until all
>   open handles for the file have been closed and the link count for the
>   file is zero. When marking a file for deletion using
>   **FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS**, the link gets removed from the visible namespace as soon as the POSIX delete handle has been closed,
>   but the file’s data streams remain accessible by other existing
>   handles until the last handle has been closed.

```
ULONG DeletePosix(PCWSTR lpFileName)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpFileName, DELETE, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS|FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, 0);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    static FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO_EX fdi = { FILE_DISPOSITION_DELETE| FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS };

    ULONG dwError = SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileDispositionInfoEx, &fdi, sizeof(fdi)) 
        ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

    // win10 rs1: file removed from parent folder here
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of things that I don't understand in this answer - are you claiming that this function will delete the file and not return until the file is *fully* deleted (like my suggested super_delete() in the OP)?

Comment: @Mick - `DeletePosix`  remove from the visible namespace. as result you can create/rename new file with this name. if no other opened handles to this file - it will be just deleted, otherwise only when last open handle will be closed. and if exist section on file - this call fail. but in this case all fail. if your DeleteFile not fail - this mean no section on file in your concrete case

Comment: @Mick - so if exist additional open handles on file - it will be not fully deleted - this impossible, until handles not closed. but it name will be removed(unlinked) from folder. and you can rename to this name

Comment: @Mick - anyway - this is generic concept even from c++ view - object(file) can not be deleted until exist reference(handles) to it. `DeleteFile` can not just delete file. it can only mark it for deletion when last object reference closed/released. if exist external references - it can be exist indefinitely long - if wait for this - `DeleteFile` can never return. so by design - it return just, but file can still exist indefinitely long after this. new (from win 10 rs1) functional - let remove file name, unlik it. so file still will be exist but invisible and not hold name - rename not fail

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Sorry i didn't get the question correctly the first time. I thought DeleteFile returned error 13.

Now I understand that DeleteFile succeeds but rename fails immediatlely after.
It *could* be just a sync issue with the filesystem. After calling DeleteFile the file will be deleted when the OS commits the changes to the filesystem. That may not appen immediately.
If you need to perform multiple operations to the same path, you should have a look at transactions https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefiletransacteda.

-- OLD ANSWER --

That is correct. If the another application handles to that file, DeleteFile will fail.
Citing MSDN docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile :

`The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that has other handles open for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file (FILE_SHARE_DELETE must have been specified when other handles were opened).`

This applies to dropbox, the antivirus, or in general, any other application that may open those files. 
Dropbox may open the file to compute its hash (to look for changes) at any moment. Same goes with the antivirus.

Comment: The OP mentions that `DeleteFile()` *never* returns a failure.

Comment: From the doc you link I feel this is much more interesting: "*The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed.*"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated my answer accordingly. Yes, DeleteFile will not delete the file immediately, that's why a subsequent call to rename may fail.

Comment: "*DeleteFile will not delete the file immediately*" I feel this function then is entirely broken.

Comment: I agree the name is misleading. It should be something like MarkForDeletion. It has been discussed before here on so: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530730/delete-a-file-instead-of-marking-it-for-deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530730/delete-a-file-instead-of-marking-it-for-deletion)